# Create a dynamic vhost in apache

Tags: apache, webserver, apache2, vhosts

All my vhost are the same way and I dont want to create for every project a new one so I thought there is maybe a way to match the `project_name` `environment` based on the domain which call the webserver.

My current Vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/l91/Development/<project_name>/web"
    ServerName <project_name>.<environment>

    <Directory "/Users/l91/Development/<project_name>/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
        SetEnv SYMFONY_ENV <environment>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more like you're looking for aliases or rewrites, rather than a virtual host. You can likely use [rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to find them dynamically.

Comment: you know how I could set the environment with it? `SetEnv SYMFONY_ENV <environment>`

Comment: Yes, you can [set environment variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e) with it, too.

Comment: Do you have an example to set it by header I'm not very good at this configuration things I tried this

    SetEnv SYMFONY_ENV dev
    SetEnvIf X-SYMFONY_ENV "stage" SYMFONY_ENV stage
    SetEnvIf X-SYMFONY_ENV "prod" SYMFONY_ENV prod

but it keeps to be `dev`

Answer (score 1):

Did get it to work with this configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory "/Users/l91/Development/Websites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/l91/Development/Websites/%0/web

SetEnvIf X-SYMFONY_ENV "^prod$" SYMFONY_ENV=prod
SetEnvIf X-SYMFONY_ENV "^stage$" SYMFONY_ENV=stage
SetEnvIf SYMFONY_ENV "^$" SYMFONY_ENV=dev
```

and  use of the following plugin to change ENVs by setting a header: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj